# Is there a way for JS to detect that the bottom of a div has been reached, rather than the bottom of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this at the moment:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      $(".initial").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
          $(".secondary").fadeIn("slow");
      });
    }
});
```

And I've tried fiddling around with `window` and replacing it with div names and static pixel values for the scroll to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Replace `$(document).height()` by `(`[`$(elem).offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)`+`[`$(elem).outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)`)`

Comment: still having some trouble.. could you please paste the entire code block? Thanks